# How to move a view in only three directions

Tags: android, user-interface, android-view, ontouchlistener

I am using onTouch Listener to move the view in 2 directions left and right , Now I want to move my view in Upwards also , it should move only in a straight line like x positive axis and negative , and also y positive axis only . I am doing the following code to implement this functionality .

I want my view should move like this :

```
           up
            ^
            |
  left<---- | ---->right

public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

    switch (event.getAction()) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            dX = view.getX() - event.getRawX();
            dY = view.getY() - event.getRawY();
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

            view.animate()
                    .x(event.getRawX() + dX)
                    .y(event.getRawY() + dY)
                    .setDuration(0)
                    .start();
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Use a gestureDetector with the onScroll method to do that.